# iOS SQLite or 1000 loose files?

Tags: ios, sqlite

Suppose I have 1000 records of variable size, ranging from around 256 bytes to a few K.  I wonder is there any advantage of putting them into a sqlite database versus just reading/writing 1000 loose files on iOS?  I don't need to do any operations other than access by a single key, which I can use as the filename.  Seems like the file system would be the winner unless the number of records grows very large.

Comment: It depends a bit on the fashion in which you use them, but using SQLite "blobs" or char fields would probably be a better choice when the number of such files exceeds a hundred or so.

Answer (score 3):

If your system were read-only, I would say that the file system is the clear winner: a simple binary file and perhaps a small index to know where each record starts would be all that you need. You could read the entire index into memory, and then grab your records from the file system as needed, for a performance that would be extremely tough to match for any RDBMS.

However, since you are planning on writing data back, I would suggest going with SQLite because of potential data integrity issues.

Performance concerns should not be underestimated, too: since your records are of variable size, writing the data back may prove to be difficult in cases when records need to expand. Moreover, since you are on a mobile platform, you would need to build something in to avoid data corruption when the program is killed unexpectedly in the middle of a write. SQLite takes care of this; your code would have to build something comparable to it, or risk data corruption problems.

Comment: Another vote in favor of SQLite for this is that 1000 files take more disk space and take a lot more time to copy than a single database file containing the same amount of data.

Comment: Your first paragraph probably [is wrong](http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html).

Comment: @CL. The tests are not for the scenario I describe. The page at the link discusses a situation when there is a SQLite table anyway, plus the data in the blobs. In that situation you have already "paid" with time for accessing the file name inside the database by loading the appropriate page, so when your BLOBs are small, you can get them with relatively little overhead. I am describing a situation when the entire indexing structure, whatever that may be, is so tiny that it fits in main memory. Then there would be virtually zero overhead to reading from file.

Comment: I am talking about writing each record/blob as it's own file, so there is no issue with resizing or integrity.  That is what the file system should be good at.  Use the btree or whatever the file system uses as the index to the file names.  I think the main concern is hogging space in that system resource.  I will not be doing any mass copies of these files myself, but I guess the OS may do that for backups and this would add overhead there.

Comment: @user1055568 The file system of iOS should have no trouble handling 1000 files. Also, [iOS lets you mark files for exclusion from backup to iTunes/iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html), so there should be no worries there. If you plan to store one "record" per file, you are risking the integrity of at most the number of files opened at the same time for writing, which is usually very few, so you should be good here.